# WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to unmarshall response (Failed to parse XML document with handler

Tags: apache-spark

Anyone have experience with this kind of error?  I'm seeing this error when running spark 2.0.1 jobs using the s3a protocol.

I'm also seeing sporadic failures of `saveAsTextFile` to s3. I think it's recovering at least sometimes.

Trying to find a direction, if it's the pyspark implementation, or s3a properties, limits, timeouts, or something else.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was after running spark jobs for almost a year we accumulated a lot of files under the same S3 path. S3 performance was the issue.  All I did was change the top level "subdir" so paths on newly created files were different and performance dramatically improved.

Answer (score 0):

Good to hear this fix.

If you see it again, can you add the stack trace to a JIRA at issues apache org, project HADOOP, component fs/s3? This may show us where we can do a bit more retry logic on failing operations.